# Whats the best way to send data from a (WAGO) PLC to an cloud database?

Tags: logging, amazon-dynamodb, cloud, plc

Whats the best way to send data from a (WAGO) PLC to an (DynamoDB) cloud database?

Our situation:

We have WAGO PLC's(750-880, 750-882, 750-890) installed on site and we would like to send multiple data to an cloud database, preferabel an AWS DynamoDB. Whats the best approach how to achieve this? Is there an universal solution or a specific WAGO solution for this?

Comment: Do not use DynamoDB for that. It will be very expensive!  Use RDS. I created cloud service for that www.icod.cloud. Right now this can collect registers over Modbus TCP and write from cloud. Right now I am working on archiving data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did answer a similar question

[Where should I start with my OPC-UA client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209686/where-should-i-start-with-my-opc-ua-client/58211410#58211410)

If you are just looking to move data from a PLC to a database then take a look at Node-Red. Here is a video that should help you get started. Node-Red can do OPC-UA or just talk direct to the PLC with out the need for OPC in the middle it's your choice. If you need more help just ask!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaUmhhMdoyY

Node-Red can also do the GUI.

For the reporting you can use https://grafana.com/.

If you would like a good Database to log to look at https://www.timescale.com/.

Grafana and Timescale work well together!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a process running on some server that read the Wago Input/Output and publish it on your server.

You will need to create a socket to port 502 of Wago talking using ModbusTCP, normally you can find some libraries around depending on which programming language you use. After acquiring data you will publish to your database.

Following a link to a Control Software that talks with Wago using this protocol. It is not a barebone example at all, but may give you some ideas.
[Bliss Project ESRF - Wago controller](https://gitlab.esrf.fr/bliss/bliss/-/blob/master/bliss/controllers/wago/wago.py)
don't esitate to ask if you need help.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your anwer. I'm kinda new to PLC programming etc. Can you explain in less technical details? From the plc I have to sent data to a server and from this server to my cloud database? How do i sent my data to a server and how do i sent data from server into cloud database?

Comment: When I am talking about a server I mean a computer that is in the same local network of the PLC and that can be left turned on. Could be your PC for example, or a PC that is left turned on. In this PC you need to create a software that 1) reads the PLC using, for example ModbusTCP. 2) Once gathered the data the same software will send the data to your AWS DynamoDB.